# Binding data in a maui content view

Tags: maui

In my maui app I have this content view that I use as a custom control. In it I have a collectionview that I want to bind to a list of data.

I use DI for my services and have a BaseService with all the httpclient requests and I then inherit from that BaseService depending of model.

I then have a viewmodel where I inject the service and retreive data from an api.

---

```cs
private readonly LightCastArchiveService _lightCastArchiveService;
private readonly LightCastChannelService _lightCastChannelService;
   
public LatestViewModel(LightCastArchiveService lightCastArchiveService,
        LightCastChannelService lightCastChannelService)
{
    _lightCastArchiveService = lightCastArchiveService;
    _lightCastChannelService = lightCastChannelService;
}
```

---

And in the viewmodel I then have a method to get the data:

```cs
public async Task LoadVideos()
    {
        if (IsLoading) return;
        try
        {
            string url = EndPoints.ArchiveEndpoint + $"&count=50";
            IsLoading = true;
            if (Videos.Any()) Videos.Clear();
            var videos = new List<LCVideo>();
            videos = await _lightCastArchiveService.Get(url);
            foreach (var video in videos)
            {
                Videos.Add(video);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get the videos: {ex.Message}");
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "Failed to retrieve list of videos.", "Ok");
        }
        finally
        {
            IsLoading = false;
            IsRefreshing = false;
        }
    }
```

In an content page I then can use the OnAppearing method to retrieve the videos:

```cs
 protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await _homeViewModel.GetCarouselItems(1025, 10);
        await _homeViewModel.LoadLiveChannels();
        await _homeViewModel.GetItems(1009, 20);
        await _homeViewModel.LoadVideosForAllChannels();
        
    }
```

but how can I do it in an content view (I tried the approach below but it didn't work)?

````cs
public partial class Latest : ContentView
{
    private readonly LatestViewModel _latestViewModel;
    private readonly LightCastArchiveService _lightCastArchiveService;
    private readonly LightCastChannelService _lightCastChannelService;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public Latest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        .BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;

        _lightCastArchiveService = new LightCastArchiveService(_client);
        _lightCastChannelService = new LightCastChannelService(_client);

        this.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;

        _latestViewModel = new LatestViewModel(_lightCastArchiveService, _lightCastChannelService);
        BindingContext = _latestViewModel;
    }

    private async void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BindingContext is LatestViewModel viewModel)
        {
            await viewModel.LoadVideos();
        }
    }

    // private async void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    // {
    //     if (e.PropertyName == nameof(_latestViewModel.Videos))
    //     {
    //         latestVideos.BindingContext = await _latestViewModel.LoadVideos();
    //     }
    // }
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Unless it's a very complex custom control, you probably want to avoid a viewmodel for a `ContentView`.

Let me justify this. I'm not saying it's completely wrong, nor impossible, but as you've seen, many features you have in `Page`s viewmodels are not there for `ContentView`s ones (injected services, appearing events...).
Someone could actually say that you shouldn't use `OnAppearing()` to call viewmodel methods, but I'm not such a purist.

If you think about MAUI controls, they don't have their own viewmodel, but they inherit the ancestor's `BindingContext` (probably the one belonging to the `Page` where they are used) and provide bindable properties you can bind to a viewmodel property. You should do that too.

Take a look at [how `BindableProperties` work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-8.0), if you don't know what I'm talking about.

---

If you really want to keep your viewmodel, you could instantiate it inside the `ContentPage` code-behind and set the `BindingContext` of `LatestView` there. This way, you can call `LatestViewModel` methods inside `OnAppearing`. Dirty workaround though.